# I want get Product_id from 'sales/quote_item' but only i have quote_id not Item_id?

Tags: magento-1.9

The do so i have used below code but it iswn't working

```
 $productId = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')
                           ->addAttributeToSelect(array('product_id'))
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('quote_id', array('eq' => $quoteid))
                            ->load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$storeid = "your_store_id"; 
 $store = Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load($storeid);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($store)->load($quote_id);

$allItems = $quote->getAllItems();

foreach($allItems as $item){
   echo $productId = $item->getProductId()."<br>";
}
```

So basically you are getting the quote first and then loading all the items of that quote, then you can grab the product id (resides in table `sales_flat_quote_item`) from there.